# Erro no script desta pagina

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou tentando iniciar os estudos em C# com visual studio, porem quando executo o código ocorre o seguinte erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já pesquisei sobre o ocorrido mas não consegui encontrar o porque disto estar acontecendo

Comment: Evite colocar imagens do seu código. Coloque o próprio código formatado na sua questão.

Comment: Me parece que isso está relacionado ao Visual Studio e não o seu código. Esse erro sempre ocorre quando você tenta executar o código?

Comment: Sim, ocorre e o código não executa. Eu também acho q seja algo relacionado ao visual studio, mas não tenho ideia do q seja. Eu já pesquisei em diversos lugares mas só encontro essa menssagem d erro ligada ao Internet Explorer

Comment: @JoãoMartins nesse caso o problema não é exatamente no código mas sim em algo q eu talvez não tenha feito para o visual studio funcionar da maneira correta. Seria muito trabalhoso explicar nesse caso q o erro não é do código sem uma imagem, mas mesmo assim agradeço pelo conselho.

Comment: Reinstale ou atualize o seu visual studio, o problema deverá parar de acontecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desabilita essa opção aqui no seu VS:

Tools > Options > Debugging> General > Enable Diagnostic Tools

Essa solução é paliativa, o ideal é atualizar o IE pra versão 11.